# How to pass the path of a picture to display with kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Please forgive me, I'm new in python and kivy. Sorry too for my bad English.

I'm trying to display picture as and when they are taken with kivy.
My problem is that the path of the photo is different each time, I can't just write `source : 'path'` like for the background of my screen. `

How I can pass the path who is contain in filename to my kv file ? I'm totally lost between python/kivy, it's probably very simple but I'm not able to find a solution.

Part of my python file :

```
class CountdownScreen(Screen):
    def capture(self, nbr_rep):
        for i in range(nbr_rep):
            sleep(4)
            self.dslr = Gphoto()
            self.filename = self.dslr.capture_image()

class DisplayPicture(Screen):
    pass

class PhotoboothApp(App):
    countdown = CountdownScreen()
    def build(self):
        return RootScreen()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    PhotoboothApp().run()
```

Part of my kv file :

```
<ChooseScreen>:
    name: "choose"
    FloatLayout:
        Image: #Background
            source: "Interface_PNG/Page_3.png"
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: False
            size_hint: 1, 1
        Button: #1
            id: b1
            background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
            size_hint : 0.3, 0.5
            pos_hint: {'x' : 0.025, 'center_y' : 0.5}
            on_release: root.manager.current = "countdown"
            on_release: app.countdown.capture(1)

<DisplayPicture>:
    name: "display_picture"
    FloatLayout:
        Image: #Background
            source: 'Interface_PNG/Page_6.png'
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: False
            size_hint: 1, 1
        Image: #Picture
            source: ???
            keep_ratio: False
            allow_stretch: True
            size_hint: 0.67, 0.72
            pos_hint: {'center_x' : 0.565, 'center_y' : 0.50}
```

Comment: How and when do you determine the picture? Does it change on runtime? is it by user or through an automatic process?

Comment: @anishtain4 thanks for your help. Picture come from a DSLR. On the first screen, user click on the button and a picture was take. My objective is to display this picture on the second screen. The filename change at each time picture was taken. All is automatic, user just click on the button, nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From kivy's [`Image`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.image.html) documentation:

> reload()
>
> Reload image from disk. This facilitates
>   re-loading of images from disk in case the image content changes.
>
> Usage:
>
> ```
> im = Image(source = '1.jpg')
> # -- do something --
> im.reload()
> # image will be re-loaded from disk
> ```

You can also change the source path before reloading if you'd like.

```
im.source = "new_source.png"
```

Remember that these changes have to be done programatically, so you have to trigger them somehow in your code, for example via a button press.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it.